# Calculate total work days in a month using the month name

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula that will count all the work days in a month based on the month name. I am having a hard time trying to find information through Google on how to solve this without installing a 3rd party plugin, or writing it in VBA.

My table looks like this:

[image: table example]

And the formula I am playing around with looks like this

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(MONTH(A2),MONTH(A2),17)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since it looks like the month name is a string `Month(A2)` will return an error.  to get a date you will need to create a full string that Excel can use to return a date:

```
DATEVALUE("1 " & A2 & YEAR(TODAY()))
```

Using that and EOMONTH for the end date we get:

```
=NETWORKDAYS.INTL(DATEVALUE("1 " & A2 & YEAR(TODAY())),EOMONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & A2 & YEAR(TODAY())),0),17)
```

[image]